# Get userId from Spotify iOS SDK

Tags: ios, spotify

Is there a way to get the *userId* using the Spotify iOS SDK rather than using the web api?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking, but SPTSession has a property:

```
/** @brief The canonical username of the authenticated user. */
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *canonicalUsername;
```

Which seems to be the id needed to make requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here's an example of how to do it in Swift 3:

```
SPTUser.requestCurrentUser(withAccessToken:(SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.accessToken)!) { (error, data) in
        guard let user = data as? SPTUser else { print("Couldn't cast as SPTUser"); return }
        let userId = user.canonicalUsername
})
```